# Equating a variable to "this" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store a table row inside a window variable

```
window.row = this
```

where `this = <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td></tr>`

However, as a class is added to `this`

```
<tr class="checked"><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td></tr>
```

`window.row` also changes to above.

How can I prevent `window.row` from being changed each time that the `this` is changed.

Comment: So what you want is a variable that holds a copy of the element that is not live? cloneNode() comes to mind !

Comment: If what you need is access to the actual element, and you are not using jQuery, then you can use `window.row = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("id"))`, to select the actual, live element.

Comment: This is easier with jQuery - `window.row = jQuery(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `row` to be the string `"<tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td></tr>"`, use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML):

```
window.row = this.outerHTML;
```

If you want `row` to an HTML element like `this`, use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode):

```
window.row = this.cloneNode(true); // Use true argument to clone descendants too
```

Note the clone approach doesn't copy event listeners nor properties.